# Kivy ListView refresh

Tags: python, listview, kivy

Hallo I’ve a List View and I want to use it as a Logger.

I’ve try to do this Job with

```
ListView:
    id: x
    item_strings: []

x.item_string.appned(‘frank’)

or

ListView:
    id: x
    adapter:
        sla.SimpleListAdapter(data=[], cls=label.Label)


x.adapter.data.append(‘frank’)
```

That works. But I see 1000 Rows in the list after the whole Job is done. But I want to see that after one insert into the array the value should be show directly in the view.

I’ve watched for a kind of List View refreshment after one insert or something like this but I couldn't find some

Any Idea.

Thanks

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Key is multithreading.

```
ListView:
    id: logger
    adapter:
        sla.SimpleListAdapter(data=[], cls=label.Label)

def logger(self, logger):
  for counter in range(0, 1000):
    logger.item_string.insert(0, str(counter) + ' log entry')

thread.start_new_thread(logger, (self.logger))
```

That works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably know from the docs that the ListView API ist still under construction and experimental at the time. What might help in your case is to call the private and therefore undocumented ListView method _trigger_reset_populate() immediately after appending an item:

```
x.adapter.data.append(‘frank’)
x._trigger_reset_populate()
```